# NodeJs/Electron : How to wait for function to finish before ipcMain send back his answer?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am learning nodejs and electron and I am trying to receive data from my renderer, treats those data, and send them back to it. But my treat function is too slow or I don't really know and so the ipc send back the data too early and make undefined data.
In short, I want my treat function to finish before the ipcMain event send back a message.
Here's just an example of where I am stuck, it's not my real code though, I can send you the real but it's really messy, like a lot..

```
// In main process.
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')

function treatData (input) {
var treated = treat(input)
    // ...
console.log(treated) // prints the actual treated data
return treated;
}

ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, rawdata) => {
  console.log(rawdata) // prints my raw data
  var dataTreated = treatData(rawdata)
  console.log(dataTreated) // prints Undefined
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', dataTreated) // send Undefined data
})
```

As i'm learning new things everyday, I am often stuck to basic stuff I think... But here am I and I need your help. I've already looked for problem like mine but I can't find anything because I don't know what the problem is actually called. 
I searched around for asynchronous function with async and await but I don't know how possible I can put them here. Because async seems to doesn't work with ipcMain or I don't know what am I missing but that doesn't work :

```
async function RenderMessage () {
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, rawdata) => {
  console.log(rawdata) // prints my raw data
  var dataTreated = await treatData(rawdata)
  console.log(dataTreated) // prints Undefined
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', dataTreated) // send Undefined data
 })
}
```

It returns "await is a reserved word"

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is a post explaining possible missing async keywords https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527490/error-using-async-await-in-react-native/36532046#36532046

Comment: take a look at this answer to a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51748499/2550156

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You miss two important things to achieve a callback waiting up another function:

1. Your function (to be waited) should return a `Promise` object for being able to [be `await`ed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
2. Your callback should be an `async` function for being able to `await`

```js
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')

function treatData (input) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var treated = treat(input)
    // ...
    resolve(treated)
  })
}
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', async (event, rawdata) => {
  var dataTreated = await treatData(rawdata)
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', dataTreated)
})
```

Comment: also note, you can do this more easily in more recent electron versions with [`ipcMain.handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) and [`ipcRenderer.invoke`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)

Answer (score 3):

Your code may be missing the `async` keyword. So it should be

```
function sendMessage () {
  ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', async (event, rawdata) => {
    console.log(rawdata) // prints my raw data
    var dataTreated = await treatData(rawdata)
    console.log(dataTreated) // prints Undefined
    event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', dataTreated) // send Undefined data
   })
}
```

Comment: How can I isolate the "event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', dataTreated)" out of my function ? I shouldn't have it named sendMessage, sorry.. 
I still want to receive message from my renderer. Because if I call the function at the end of my treat function it'll just send nothing because I never receive the raw data out of the function, right?
I already tried to just remove the function but it does the same thing as before, sending undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your **treatData()** function has asynchronous behavior.
Make following changes:

```
// In main process.
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')

async function treatData (input) {
  try{
    var treated = treat(input)
    // ...
    console.log(treated) // prints the actual treated data
    return treated;
  }
  catch(err){
    // handle error
  }

}

ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', async (event, rawdata) => {
  console.log(rawdata) // prints my raw data
  var dataTreated = await treatData(rawdata)
  console.log(dataTreated) // will print the actual data
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', dataTreated)
})
```

And if your **treat()** function contains some asynchronous code then make it async and use,

```
var treated = await treat(input)
```